# sql group_concat and subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat

I have 2 mysql tables:

```
 car_model:
    id (int) (Primary Key)
    title (varchar)
    id_brand (int) FK to car_brand table



 car__car_model: - relation many to many
     id_model (int) 
     id_advice_model (int)
```

In car__car_model there are the following data:

```
(id_model)  (id_advice_model)
12          12
12          45
12          67
12          78
13          13
13          12
13          67
13          105
```

And I want to fetch this data like this:

```
12    12,45,67,78
13    13.12.67,105
```

I use group_concat and group by like this:

```
SELECT ccm.id_model,group_concat(ccm.id_advice_model) FROM car__car_model as ccm  group by ccm.id_model
```

**Question:**
How can fetch titles from car_model table for this string if ids - for example for 12,45,67,78. And I want to do it in 1 query - to customize my query

**Updated:** 
And Now I have another question:
I Have one more table:

```
 car_brand:
    id (int) (PK)
    title (varchar)
```

and in my car_model table there is a field **id_brand**

**Question 2:**
How can i fetch title form car_brand with the title from car_model - like this - Ford Focus, Fiat Linea and so on  - Now I get (with you help) to fetch only title from car_model
Now I have:  12 - Focus,Linea

**Updated:**
I solve this problem using -

```
SELECT 
id_model,group_concat(concat(cb.title,' ',cm.title))
FROM 
car__car_model as ccm  
inner join car_model cm on (cm.id = ccm.id_advice_model) 
inner join car_brand cb on (cb.id=cm.id_brand)
group by ccm.id_model
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this::

```
SELECT 
ccm.id_model,group_concat(cm.tile, SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM 
car__car_model as ccm  
inner join car_model cm on (cm.id = ccm.id_advice_model) 
group by ccm.id_model
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT ccm.id_model, 
       group_concat(cm.title) 
FROM car__car_model as ccm
inner join car_model cm on cm.id = ccm.id_advice_model
group by ccm.id_model
```

You can replace the ids with the actual title by joining the `car_model` table on the ids you like to replace.

Comment: It wasn't similar from the start ;)