# group concat from subquery very slow

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

Coming from here [sql group_concat and subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311679/sql-group-concat-and-subquery)

I managed to "solve" de problem by doing this a "subquery":

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(name,',',results separator '#')
as finalresult 
FROM
(

    select t.name as name, group_concat(distinct r.idResult separator '-') as results
    from threshold t
    left join threshold_results r on r.idThreshold = t.idThreshold 
    group by t.idThreshold, t.name

) final
```

But it is too slow when there are many records, withouth the subquery the initial solution performs very well. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it better to run only the inner query and do the final concatenation in the client code? The outer query does not run any database-specific processing, it just concatenate some strings and this could be achieved with better results (regarding the speed) in the client code.

Comment: I thought it was faster to do it in the database rather than in the client code.

Comment: If you run the subquery on its own, how does it perform? What sort of performance differences (in terms of seconds) are you seeing?

Comment: subquery duration less than 1 second, final query about 14 seconds

Answer (score 1):

add index on r.idThreshold, t.name

Comment: It already has index, I think the problem is the main GROUP_CONCAT if I add more fields it gets even slower, maybe I will have to try to do it, from the client code